# Trying to set up WebLogic Server but can't locate the JDK

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to set up the WebLogic Server for a class and since I had to download the jar file (because that's what is provided for mac), it doesn't come with a JDK. We are supposed to use our own. My problem is that I can't get it to "see" my JDK.

I have, after searching long and hard, found my JDK folders in Mac>Library>Java> After that there are a few options(Extensions, JavaConfig.plist, JavaVirtualMachines, Support). Within each of these are more and more options…where is the actual "file" that I can point WLS to? Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with MAC. But in linux installation the JDK is primarily referenced in the following files:

```
#$MIDDLEWARE_HOME/registry.xml
#$MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
#$MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/base_domain/init-info/domain-info.xml
#$MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/base_domain/init-info/startscript.xml
#$MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/base_domain/init-info/tokenValue.properties
```

Assuming my domain name is "base_domain".

Change the refernce to your JDK in those files. The 2nd file though, is the key.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm having other installation issues now, though…oh well. Going to post a Q about it too in case anyone has experience with it...

Comment: No problem. Post a link to your questions here and I'll see if I can answer.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I was trying to using a 32 bit JVM installer, while my computer actually has a 64bit JVM…So that's been cleared up. Now I'm trying to start up weblogic.admin, but can't seem to find it anywhere. It was deprecated a few versions of WLS ago (9.0), but supposedly it is still here. But I can't seem to locate it to start it up (I tried searching with Finder, and it doesn't see it. At least, not by that name). Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Try the web based admin console. The default URL is 
    http://localhost:7001/console.

Use the IP address if the server isn't local.

Of course this URL is available if only your weblogic server is running.

Comment: Do you mean that I can start weblogic.admin from there? I tried searching on it…how do I do that?
Or do you mean to use that instead? How would I issue commands through it (I'm very new to this--it is for a class--as is probably obvious… :) )

Comment: Oh, I think you are talking about the command line. Right. So, yes, you can use the console instead. Almost all admin commands have an equivalent piece in the console. I'd use the command line when I'm automating a set of tasks on the WLS. The console however, is only available when WLS is started. As for starting the server, weblogic comes with a startup script; something like startWeblogicServer.sh.

Comment: Everything is working! Thanks for all your help! And, I noticed your first name…Atah Yehudi? Gam Ani! Todah rabbah, v'hatzlacha rabba b'chol ma'asecha! ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that. And, no, I'm not.

Comment: Ah, sorry then. But then I still assume we are "cousins," no? Otherwise I'm just totally off...

Comment: :) You aren't totally off.